# Как вывести базу данных(Python)?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

__connection = None

def get_connection():
    global __connection
    if __connection is None:
        __connection = sqlite3.connect('anketa.db')
    return __connection


def init_db(force: bool = False):
    conn = get_connection()

    c = conn.cursor()

    if force:
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_message')

    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_message (
                id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                text    TEXT NOT NULL,
                date DATETIME  NOT NULL
              )
        ''')

    conn.commit()

def read_table(records):
    conn = get_connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM user_message')
    records = c.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        print("id:", row[0])
        print("user_id:", row[1])
        print("text:", row[2])
        print("date:", row[3])
        print(end="\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    read_table()
```

Что я делаю не так?
Ошибка: **TypeError: read_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'records'**

Делаю через функции, так как потом я вызываю ее в главном файле для вывода в телеграм.

Comment: read_table принимает параметр records, а он:
1) не нужен там, т.к. не используется + вытаскивается из БД
2) не передаётся при вызове read_table.
Внимательнее читайте ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите параметр `records` у функции `read_table`:

```py
def read_table():
    ...
```

---

### Подробнее

Ваша ошибка переводится как

> ОшибкаТипа: read_table() не принимает 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: 'records'

Формальным исправлением было бы передать его:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    records = ...
    read_table(records)
```

Но в самой функции Вы не используете его, а переопределяете результатом вызова `c.fetchall()`:

```py
def read_table(records):
    ...
    records = c.fetchall()
```

Поэтому удаление параметра не изменит поведение функции и устранит ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.